# Spinner issues: How do I call list items within the spinner and use math for each one separately?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a snippet of code I've been working on with four conversion ratios depending on what unit conversion option is picked within the spinner. How would I call each individual ratio depending on what the user selects.

**For Example**, If option 1 is selected in the spinner then the conversion to use would be `Miles to Kilometers` or `resultOutput = userInput * 1.6093` Since the conversion would be a userInput of miles then kilometers results in the `miles * 1.6093`. Now how would I inject that and multiple other if statements into this source code? Would I create a new method or just do it right inside `public void onItemSelected`?

**Would I type:** `if(conversionType = list.get(0)){
                       resultOutput = userInput * 1.6093`?

I just need a general direction on where to go with this as I have been stuck on it for a few days. Thanks for any help available!

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.corey.unitconversionappbycoreywhitlow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner spinnerConversions;
    TextView conversionFrom, conversionTo, outputResult;
    EditText userInput;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        conversionFrom = findViewById(R.id.fromValue);
        conversionTo = findViewById(R.id.toValue);
        outputResult = findViewById(R.id.resultOutput);
        userInput = findViewById(R.id.numInput);
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
        spinnerConversions = findViewById(R.id.conversionSpinner);
        spinnerConversions.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        list.add("Miles to Kilometers");
        list.add("Kilometers to Miles");
        list.add("Inches to Centimeters");
        list.add("Centimeters to Inches");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource
             (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);    

        spinnerConversions.setAdapter(adapter);
        String conversionType = list.get(1);
        String[] units = conversionType.split("to");
        String conFrom = units[0].trim();
        String conTo = units[1].trim();

        conversionFrom.setText(conFrom);
        conversionTo.setText(conTo);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made changes to your code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner spinnerConversions;
    TextView conversionFrom, conversionTo, outputResult;
    EditText userInput;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        conversionFrom = findViewById(R.id.fromValue);
        conversionTo = findViewById(R.id.toValue);
        outputResult = findViewById(R.id.resultOutput);
        userInput = findViewById(R.id.numInput);

        spinnerConversions = findViewById(R.id.conversionSpinner);

        list.add("Miles to Kilometers");
        list.add("Kilometers to Miles");
        list.add("Inches to Centimeters");
        list.add("Centimeters to Inches");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinnerConversions.setAdapter(adapter);

        String conversionType = list.get(0);
        String[] units = conversionType.split("to");
        String conFrom = units[0].trim();
        String conTo = units[1].trim();

        conversionFrom.setText(conFrom);
        conversionTo.setText(conTo);

        spinnerConversions.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Double d = 0.0;
                try {
                    d = Double.parseDouble(userInput.getText().toString().trim());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                outputResult.setText(d * 1.6093 + "");

                break;
            case 1:
                //Do something

                break;
            case 2:
                //Do something

                break;
            case 3:
                //Do something

                break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){}

}
```

You had a lot of initialization code in `onItemSelected` but it should be placed in your activity's `onCreate()`  
The `switch` statement allows you to choose what to do with the user's choice. You will make there the conversions you need.  
In `onCreate()` you have all the initialization code: variables and views declarations, setting the adapter and the listener for the spinner etc.

Comment: Awesome that is a huge help! The only question I have now is when setting up each individual case, how do I call the spinner with object 1 selected, objected 2 selected etc.

**For example** `case 0: if(itemSelected = 0){ resultOutput = userInput * 1.6093;}` ?? I'm just not really sure how to write out the math depending on which option is selected. I know the ratios needed but how would i select okay do this math when option 1 in the spinner is selected?

Comment: No, 0 means the user chose "Miles to Kilometers", 1 the user chose"Kilometers to Miles", etc. Remember that lists in Java are zero-based. So you have to write code for each case of selection made by the user. No ifs in there.

Comment: Okay for `case 0: outputResult = userInput *1.6093;` I'm getting an error that says Operator '*' cannot be applied to 'android.widget.EditText', 'double'

So how do I change it from type double? Which I thought double allowed for the use of decimals which I want to use

Comment: First you extract the string from userinput, then you cast it to number `d` and then you set it as text to outputresult

Comment: Okay I typed everything out and got an error in the logcat. I will post my new code that I built along with the logcat results

Comment: See the changes I made.

Comment: Okay that allowed the application to run but the text boxes on the left stay continuous on `Miles` and `Kilometers` no matter which spinner option I select. I'm also obviously missing something in each of the cases though as the `outputResult` isn't working. When I type anything in the `userInput` box the result box stays at `0.0`. Is there any hint on what that might be?

**ALSO:** what did the try and catch block do that you added? Why did that make it work?

Comment: This is what you asked in your question: the calculation is done the moment the user makes his selection from the spinner.

Comment: Yes I was mistaken the application does work I just have to select the spinner option it doesn’t automatically work on the default selection. Do you know what I’m doing wrong in my split statement to output the correct conversion unit in the respective text boxes upon selection?

Comment: You do nothing about this.  In the switch statement you must put the code that fills the textviews just like you do in onCreate() for the 0 option. In each case 0,1,2 or 3 must split the respective string from `list` and set the 2 string in the TextViews.

Comment: Awesome I got it all working! I appreciate your help !!

Comment: if this answer helped you accept it as the right answer

Comment: I did. I have an additional question: If I happened to add a button to clear the app what would I type to reset the spinner to the default first option? I added an additional option for `case 0` which is just a default text. If you need me to link what I have I can, the button is there but I don't know how to create the reset option for the spinner

Comment: you can set the spinner to the position you want by: `spinnerConversions.setSelection(0);` for the 1st position

Comment: Okay so I have it set and I press the button and nothing happens. This is what I have:    <br/>

`public void onClick(View view){  <br/>
      clearButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) view);<br/>
        setClearButton();<br/>



    }`

2.`private void setClearButton(){
        spinnerConversions.setSelection(0);
        outputResult.setText("0.00");
        conversionFrom.setText("Select Conversion Type");
        conversionTo.setText("Select Conversion Type");
        userInput.setText("");
    }`

Comment: Change the listener to this:         `clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setClearButton();
            }
        });`